# Static Image inside of Collection View does not display Maui

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mvvm, maui

I struggle to get an image to show up in my Maui .NET CollectionView when I use a static image in my Resource folder.

My image is placed inside the Resource folder of the project -

```
    <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
```

I set up my ViewModel and defined an Observable Property and assign the image to it.  I have tested a link as well as the path.

To get it to work  I have to add an Image source to my model and set it in my view model with a loop and I want to avoid that.

View Model:

```
foreach(var col in collection)
    {
        col.Source = "image.jpg";
    }
```

I use it on my Content Page:

```
<ContentView x:Name="WorkNotification"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:mct="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
         x:Class="DiME.Controls.WorkNotificationBackLogContentView"
         x:DataType="vm:WorkNotificationBackLogViewModel">
<CollectionView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="10" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                x:Name="CollectionViewWorkNotificationsBacklog"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding AllWorkNotificationBacklogData}" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Black}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:WorkNotificationBacklog">
            <ContentView BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Black}">
                <Grid ColumnSpacing="1" RowSpacing="2" MaximumHeightRequest="90" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Black}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Source}" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.GetAttachCommand, Source={x:Reference WorkNotification}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Qmnum}" />
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                </Grid>
            </ContentView>
        </DataTemplate>    
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
</ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

I want to use a static image inside of my Base view model and just use it in my XAML code as such but nothing comes up - so I wonder if it is impossible.  Or am I binding the data incorrectly?

```
<Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Source, Source={x:Reference WorkNotification}}" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}">
```

Comment: does it work if you hardcode the source property?

Comment: @Jason - I didn't think to do this but it does in fact work when I hard code it.

Comment: then I would expect `Source="{Binding Source}"` to work

Comment: Inside `ItemTemplate`, `Source="{Binding Source}"` only works if `Source` is part of the item's model, which question is trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

After some thought I ended up solving this by using the BindingContext with

```
<Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding BindingContext.Source, Source={x:Reference WorkNotification}}" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}">
     </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

Comment: I assume this means your viewmodel contains `public ImageSource Source { get; set }`. That was not shown in the question. BTW, your original code would have worked if the property was in the VIEW (maybe the page?) rather than the viewmodel.

Comment: Ah, I see it now: *"I set up my ViewModel and defined an Observable Property and assign the image to it. I have tested a link as well as the path."* Its always best to **show code** too.  `[ObservableProperty] ImageSource source;`? Thanks.